# setting class "active" for one li element at the time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am straggling with building buttons group when only one is active and has icon checked added.

The goal is to build the font picker:

here is my buggy js code

```
$(document).on('click', '.fonts-size-container ul li', function(){  
    var $el = $(this);
    $('li').removeClass('active');
      $el.addClass('active');
      $el.append('<i class="icon-check"></i>');
});
```

html:

```
<ul>
    <li class="no-edit" data-fontsize="8em">8 em</li>
    <li class="no-edit" data-fontsize="7em">7 em</li>
    <li class="no-edit" data-fontsize="6em">6 em</li>
    <li class="no-edit" data-fontsize="5em">5 em</li>
    <li class="no-edit" data-fontsize="4em">4 em</li>
    <li class="no-edit" data-fontsize="3.5em">3,5 em</li>
    <li class="no-edit" data-fontsize="3em">3 em</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "building buttons group?"

Comment: I guess you haven't posted the whole html code..Where is `.editor` and `.text2`??

Comment: what's wrong with the current code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code toggles the class of all `<li>` elements, my guess is you only want to affect the siblings of the clicked element and also I assume you want to remove the check icon too. The following code should work for you:

```
$(document).on('click', '.fonts-size-container ul li', function () {
    var $el = $(this);
    $el.siblings().removeClass('active').find('.icon-check').remove();
    $el.addClass('active').append('<i class="icon-check"></i>');
    var fontSize = $el.data('fontsize');
    $(this).closest(".editor").find('.text2').css('font-size', fontSize);
});
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/NrpDm/1/)**